# Class and acessibility problem c# & asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have small class like

```
public static class TSM
{

    static string TokenID = "";

    public static string GetTSM()
    {
        TokenID = new Guid().ToString();
        return TokenID;
    }

}

`GetTokenID `will return a string
```

i just call GetTokenID from my aspx page like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var token= <% =TSM.GetTSM() %>;
```

i am getting error when i am running that aspx page.

### the error is

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

please guide me what is going wrong. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bring the namespace in which this TSM class is declared into scope in your Web Page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SomeNamespace" %>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var token = '<%=TSM.GetTSM() %>';
</script>
```

or fully quote it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var token = '<%= SomeNamespace.TSM.GetTSM() %>';
</script>
```

or include it in the `<namespaces>` section of your web.config.

Remark: Notice the `''` around the `<%=TSM.GetTSM() %>` as there is no Guid type in javascript. You must use a string.

Also note that your server side code is not thread-safe because of the assignment of this static field. Also it will always generate an empty guid.

Here's how to improve it:

```
public static class TSM
{
    public static string GetTSM()
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: ya it is ok now thanks but guid is looking like  var token = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'....actually guid looks different.

Comment: @Thomas, you should use `TokenID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` if you want to generate a new guid. The Guid constructor doesn't generate a new guid.

Comment: GetTSM will return guid from server side and when i see the guid in aspx page source at runtime then i found guid like var token = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.....i think it is not a valid guid.